# cannot find symbol with input.nextInt()

Tags: java

I ran into a problem when making a rock paper scissors game, for some reason the code is not accepting it when I use `input.nextInt()`

```
    // Rock Paper Scissors Game

    int Rock = -1;
    int Paper = 0;
    int Scissors = 1;
    int Max = 1;
    int Min = -1;

    { int computer = ((int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))) + Min;

    System.out.println("Input -1 for Rock 0 for Paper and 1 for Scissors!");
    {
    int player = input.nextInt();
    return player;
    }
    if(player == computer); {
        System.out.println("Tie");
    }
    }
```

This is the full error code

```
Compilation error   time: 0 memory: 0 signal:0
Main.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
        int player = input.nextInt();
                     ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class Ideone
```

Comment: What is `input`? It isn't defined in your snippet

Comment: 1. You do not have a variable named `input`.  You need to define one (probably `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`).  2. I don't know why the lines that start with `int player` are in curly braces, but the braces don't do anything.  And the `return` will leave your method, which means can never get to the next line, which the compiler will flag as an error.  3) Remove the semicolon from `if (player == computer);`.  It's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so Java does not know what `input` means here, as you haven't declared it as anything. As far as it knows, `input` is just a bunch of jumbled letters. You have to create an **object** that can read *input* from the keyboard. You can do so like this:

```
input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Let me offer you a bit of advice as far as your code goes though:

```
// Rock Paper Scissors Game

int Rock = -1;
int Paper = 0;
int Scissors = 1;
```

For your Rock, Paper, and Scissors variables, it makes more sense to keep them all positive - and also in java the convention is to name your variables in "camelCase", where your first word begins with a lower case and every word that follows begins with a capital letter. However, these are **CONSTANTS**, which mean they will never ever ever super ever change, so we write them in capital letters. So we'll change it to:

```
int ROCK = 1; 
int PAPER = 2;
int SCISSORS = 3;
```

I'm not sure what you're doing with `Max` and `Min` here, because they aren't referenced anywhere else in your code. If that's the case, and they aren't going to change.. **ever**... you can just use ints because it is something that can be **hard-coded into your script**

```
// int Max = 1;   GET RID OF IT
// int Min = -1;  GET RID OF IT
```

Let's rename your computer choice to a variable that describes it more.. After all `computer` is not very descriptive.

Also, the format for getting a random number in a range is correct, but let's not bother with max and min variables since the numbers will never change. Also, what's with the curly braces? They aren't needed since this isn't a block.

```
int computer_choice = ((int)(Math.random() * ((3 - 1) + 1))) + 1;
```

Let's clean up the select statement a bit - because it just looks better this way. Remember, `\n` is a special character called `newline` that will put a carriage return between each line.

```
System.out.println("Input 1 for Rock. \n 2. for Paper. \n 3 for Scissors.");
```

Now we have the answer to your question: the declaration for a scanner.

```
input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

then we have the player's move calculated.

```
int player_choice = input.nextInt();
```

No need to 'return player', since that's not what we are looking for.

```
// return player; GET RID OF IT
```

Finally, we need to handle the results. Again you go a little crazy with the braces. there's no need to use braces if the `if` statement is only one line. Furthermore, you don't put semicolons after anything that takes an open brace afterwards, including loops and conditionals, like an `if` statement

```
if(player_choice == computer) 
    System.out.println("Tie");
```

You also have to handle cases besides ties, you can due so using `else if` statements that use the logical `AND` (`&&`) to combine conditions

```
else if(player_choice == 1 && computer_choice == 2)
    System.out.println("Computer wins!")
}
else if(player_choice == 2 && computer_choice == 1)
    System.out.println("You win!")
}
else if(player_choice == 3 && computer_choice == 2)
    System.out.println("You win!")
}
else if(player_choice == 2 && computer_choice == 3)
    System.out.println("Computer wins!")
}
```

And you're done! But I'm not sure you understand how the format of a java file works, so I'll put out the complete one for you

```
public class RockPaperScissorsGame {



private int ROCK = 1; 
private int PAPER = 2;
private int SCISSORS = 3;

public static void playGame(){
    int computer_choice = ((int)(Math.random() * ((3 - 1) + 1))) + 1;
    System.out.println("Input 1 for Rock. \n 2. for Paper. \n 3 for Scissors.");

    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int player_choice = input.nextInt();

    if(player_choice == computer) 
        System.out.println("Tie");
    else if(player_choice == 1 && computer_choice == 2)
        System.out.println("Computer wins!"); 
    else if(player_choice == 2 && computer_choice == 1)
        System.out.println("You win!");  
    else if(player_choice == 3 && computer_choice == 2)
        System.out.println("You win!");   
    else if(player_choice == 2 && computer_choice == 3)
        System.out.println("Computer wins!");
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    playGame();
}
```

}

Comment: Another implementation is to use an enum to represent the possible choices of ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS and to initialize each enum value with a reference to the choice that "beats" it. Only reason I mention it is because I think it demonstrates some OOP principles, might be helpful for someone learning Java to see it. However, it would require changes to how the user input is processed.

Comment: absolutely, and you could also have used a SWITCH statement. I think OP is struggling though, so seeing it spelled out with if statements seemed the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It just needs a simple correction,
What it's saying is that there is no variable type input
while naming variable for your **Scanner class** there might be a mistake so just make sure you have
`Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` that'll resolve the error & Brother as of the Other code needs some serious optimization